# Why is there a π phase shift in Fig.4 compared to R01 shown in Fig.3 in DCQE?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, interference, quantum-optics, quantum-eraser

This question is about Kim et al. delayed choice quantum eraser experiment.

[image]

[image: the whole setup]

Is it possible to adjust the phase of interference fringes from  $D_1$ and $D_2$ by adjusting the distance of $D_0$ screen?... Shouldn't they be in the same phase? Why is there a $π$ phase shift?
Is it possible to adjust the phase of them and make them form into a same interference fringe?

Comment: Could  anybody see  my  photos which  I uploaded ?they  don't  show up in my page ..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I  just find out the Kim 's  paper have already explained this question as a key point ,sort  of .  I don't know the physics and math expression in  the  paper , but I guess because The internal law of physics and mathematics universe make sure that we can't see the wave or particle at the same time ,namely ,make sure the Complementation principle works .